# rmdir erroring for unknow reason

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When entering the cmd

```
rmdir %appdata%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects /S /Q
```

I get the error file not found even though I can copy and paste that path into a windows explorer and it goes right to the spot (meaning the file is there).
Command Prompt on Windows 8.1 update 1

Comment: Did you put "double quotes" around the path? Paths with spaces need to be enclosed in double quotes, otherwise the space acts as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the exception of CMD's CD command and notepad, paths containing spaces must be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Ahh yes, been so long since I worked with batch I forgot about that. Thanks for the reminder!